# How do I configure a key binding to send a client to bling's scratch pad in awesome wm?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, window-manager, awesome, lua

I want to make a shortcut that can send a client to bling's scratchpad.

The part that initializes bling scratch pad:

```lua
local bling = require("bling")
local term_scratch = bling.module.scratchpad {
    command = "wezterm start --class spad",           -- How to spawn the scratchpad
    rule = { instance = "spad" },                     -- The rule that the scratchpad will be searched by
    sticky = true,                                    -- Whether the scratchpad should be sticky
    autoclose = true,                                 -- Whether it should hide itself when losing focus
    floating = true,                                  -- Whether it should be floating (MUST BE TRUE FOR ANIMATIONS)
    geometry = {x=360, y=90, height=900, width=1200}, -- The geometry in a floating state
    reapply = true,                                   -- Whether all those properties should be reapplied on every new opening of the scratchpad (MUST BE TRUE FOR ANIMATIONS)
    dont_focus_before_close  = false,                 -- When set to true, the scratchpad will be closed by the toggle function regardless of whether its focused or not. When set to false, the toggle function will first bring the scratchpad into focus and only close it on a second call
}
```

That key binding that failed to move the client into said scratch pad:

```lua
globalkeys = gears.table.join(
    awful.key({ modkey, "Shift" }, "h",
    function ()
        term_scratch:toggle()
    end ),
```

Documentation page that I didn't understand: https://blingcorp.github.io/bling/#/module/scratch

How should I utilize the `term_scratch:toggle()` object/function?

System: Arch linux, X11, awesome-wm, awesome-wm bling add on.

Answer (score 0):

Set a desired instance name obtained from `xprop` in the line: `rule = { instance = "spad" },`